# Preservation of the orthonormal operation in a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, linear-transformations, orthogonality

> Let $A: X\rightarrow X$ be a linear transformation, where $X$ is a inner product space. Show that, if $\|Ax\|=\|x\|$ for all $x\in X$, that 
>   $(x,y)=(Ax,Ay)$ for all $x,y \in X$. Show also that if $A$ is an onto map with the property that $(x,y)=(Ax,Ay)$ for all $x,y$ then for any subset $U\subset X, A(U^{\bot})=A(U)^{\bot}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since $A$ preserve norm $\|A(x+y)\|^{2}=\|x+y\|^{2}$
>       \begin{eqnarray*}
>     \|A(x+y)\|^{2}&=&\|Ax\|^{2}+\|Ay\|^{2}+(Ax,Ay)+(Ay,Ax)=\\
>     \|x+y\|^{2}&=&\|x\|^{2}+\|y\|^{2}+(x,y)+(y,x)
>  \end{eqnarray*}
>       or just $(Ax,Ay)+(Ay,Ax)=(x,y)+(y,x)$ using exactly the same for $x+iy$ we
>       get $-(Ax,Ay)+(Ay,Ax)=-(x,y)+(y,x)$
>       $$\begin{cases}
>              (Ax,Ay)+(Ay,Ax)&=(x,y)+(y,x)\\
>              -(Ax,Ay)+(Ay,Ax)&=-(x,y)+(y,x)
>    \end{cases}$$
>           the solution of such system is $(Ax,Ay)=(x,y)$ and it is true for all 
>           $x,y$ in $X$. now let $x\in U, y\in U^{\bot}$, 
>           $$0=(x,y)=(Ax,Ay)\Rightarrow Ay\in A(U)^{\bot}$$
>           since it is true for all $y\in U^{\bot}$ follows that $A(U^{\bot})\subset 
>         A(U)^{\bot}$, reciprocally let $u\in A(U), w\in A(U)^{\bot}$ as 
>           $A$ is a onto map there are $x\in U$ and $y\in X$ such that 
>           $u=Ax,w=Ay$, but 
>           $$0=(Ax,Ay)=(x,y)\Rightarrow y\in U^{\bot}\Rightarrow w=Ay\in A(U^{\bot})$$
>           or just $A(U)^{\bot}\subset A(U^\bot)$ then we can write 
>           $A(U)^{\bot}=A(U^\bot)$.